# Get details of Linux kernel modules in C++

Tags: c++, linux, kernel-module

In Linux, I need to get the details(viz. service exit code,status,type,etc) of all the driver modules and I tried reading `/proc/modules`. But it gives only name, size and use count. I read that `modinfo` retrieves info from `lib/modules/`,but all modules doesn't have all info in it.  From where can I get these details reliably. I am coding in `C++`.

Comment: There is no such thing as "service exit code" in Linux, please clarify. You can get some information by running `modinfo /lib/modules/path/to/module.ko`

Comment: @myaut : Oh.. I thought something similar to `exit code` will be there in `Linux` too. And regarding `modinfo`, I tried it but most modules doesnt have much info like description.

Comment: I'd suggest to make one step back and try to formulate a _problem_ not methods to solve it. "service exit codes" even "module statuses" are the methods, not the problem itself.

Comment: @user3159253 : I didn't get you..

Comment: @myaut :  I didnit know about `struct module` and I hope I can get the required info from this struct. But however including `module.h`(located in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-40/include/linux/`) gives me error as `No such file or directory`. How can I retrieve info from `module struct`?

Comment: @myaut: Yes I did,but not thoroughly. I thought, I could use the `find_module` function to get the details as I have the module name from `/proc/modules`.

Comment: @myaut : Oh!then it seems that I have to leave that and be satisfied with only those info I get from `/proc/modules`. Anyway Thankyou so much for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel modules are handled by [`struct module`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.19.1/include/linux/module.h#L213). You may write a module to get that information from in-kernel (and provide it in another `/proc` file) or use a debugger to read raw kernel memory from `/proc/kcore` .

But, the information Linux keeps per-module doesn't fit your needs:

- *service exit code* is not saved by kernel but immediately returned to `init_module()` caller as error number (i.e. `modprobe` or `insmod` tools)
- *status* -- there is no such thing. Closest is `state`, but it transitional and only used during loading
- *type* -- Linux doesn't distinguish module types

Generally speaking, you cannot get that details from **Linux**. The most useful information is already provided in `/proc/modules`.